# Queryset is Containing some items but all() method returns empty array

Tags: python, django

I have this code:

```
print(f"DEBUG 1: {queryset}")
transaction_items = queryset.all()
queryset.update(status=TRANSACTION_STATUS_COMPLETED, processing_method=PROCESSING_METHOD_MANUALLY)
print(f"DEBUG 2: {len(queryset.all())}")
```

somehow producing this result:

```
DEBUG 1: <QuerySet [<TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18259)>, <TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18258)>]>
DEBUG 2: 0
CHUAKS: [] 0
```

It's quite weird because the all() method usually return non-empty array because the queryset itself is not empty.

Try to refactor the code to be like this:

```
def complete_transaction_items_manually(self, request, queryset):
    print(f"DEBUG 1: {queryset}")
    transaction_items = queryset.all()
    print(f"DEBUG 2: {transaction_items}")
    queryset.update(status=TRANSACTION_STATUS_COMPLETED, processing_method=PROCESSING_METHOD_MANUALLY)
```

Still returning this result:

```
DEBUG 1: <QuerySet [<TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18256)>, <TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18255)>]>
DEBUG 2: <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: If your `queryset` is filtered, then it is possible that *after* the `.update(..)` the elements no longer satisfy the filter condition, and thus it returns an empty list. For example if `queryset` was `SomeModel.objects.filter(status=some_status)` with `some_status` something different than `TRANSACTION_STATUS_COMPLETED`.

Comment: Already changed to this:
```
print(f"DEBUG 1: {queryset}")
        transaction_items = queryset.all()
        queryset.update(status=TRANSACTION_STATUS_COMPLETED, processing_method=PROCESSING_METHOD_MANUALLY)
        print(f"DEBUG 2: {transaction_items}")
```

Still not working. producing this:
```
DEBUG 1: <QuerySet [<TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18256)>, <TransactionItem: TransactionItem object (18255)>]>
DEBUG 2: <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: @GalihIarasprakoso: how does such change eliminates the possibility that you are filtering out records?

Comment: I see so, when we're saving it on transaction_items = queryset.all() . when we do queryset.update() the instance of transaction_items also get updated. thanks! @WillemVanOnsem